# Python regex £ to Â char

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a program that searches through a file, looking for £ signs:

```
 r = re.compile(r"£\S*£")
 def parseData(self):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    fs = f.read()
    res = r.findall(fs)
    return res
```

For some reason, My output has Â symbols, like £fooÂ£ where the file is £foo£.

I am using python 3.4.3, if it helps.

Full file read http://pastebin.com/L7hjeg6A

Comment: can't able to reproduce, post the contents of that file.

Comment: could you explain `where the file is £foo£` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the file is encoded in one format, but you are openning the file in a different format . Most probably, the file is `utf-8` , but you are openning in some ANSI format (I saw similar issue in notepad ++ , when I changed the encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI , for `£Latitude£` ). Example to show the same behavior -

My `a.txt` -

```
£Latitude£
```

Code -

```
>>> f = open('a.txt','r')
>>> s = f.read()
>>> s
'\xc2£Latitude\xc2£'

>>> f = open('a.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
>>> s = f.read()
>>> s
'£Latitude£'
```

You need to open the file in correct encoding, by passing the encoding as argument to `open()` , like done above.

---

From [documentation of `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) -

> **encoding** is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns), but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the codecs module for the list of supported encodings.

Comment: Surely with python 3 using unicode and all that, that utf-8 would be the default?

Comment: No, actually not, the default encoding is dependent on the platform.

Comment: You can do `import  locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())` , to see what your default encoding is

Comment: Well then unicode should be the default on windows then

Comment: Actually if I am not wrong, windows still defaults to `cp1252` , though I am not 100% sure, if may just be my comp

Comment: What is cp1252 encoding then? (I have that as well)